# Mako: How to access loop variable in tag?

Tags: pylons, mako

I cannot figure out how to access the loop variable `blog_post_uri` inside a tag so that I can dynamically load content defined in another template.

```
% for blog_post_uri in blog_post_uris:
    <div class="blog-preview">
        ## This works fine
        ${blog_post_uri}

        ## This does not
        <%namespace name="blog_post" file="${blog_post_uri}" />
        ${blog_post.blog_preview()}
        <a href="blog/${blog_post.filename}">Read More...</a>
    </div>
% endfor
```

When I try to compile this template, I get the following error:

`NameError: name 'blog_post_uri' is not defined`

I also tried the `<%! attributes['uri'] = blog_post_uri %>` method (with `template.render(attributes={})`), but get the same error.